# how to rename drill-through columns in icCube?

Tags: mdx, drillthrough, iccube

Is it possible in icCube to name the columns returned from a drillthrough statement. Now they are just technical names and it is not end-user friendly?

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not possible on the server side with the MDX request. You'll have to check how to do that in your client if possible.

Note: Renaming a drillthrough column is available in icCube since 5.x ([doc](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Drillthrough.php))

Comment: Ok, I allready managed this in the client, but a download to excel of the same data did not copy the client names. Thanks